# How to modify Column Data in BigQuery Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been trying to search online however, I am only able to see how to add, remove, change a column in a table. Basically, I need to go through an entire column of email addresses in BigQuery and add a 2nd email address in each of the rows.

```
ID|Name |email
1 |Name1|email1@address.com
2 |Name2|email2@address.com
3 |Name3|email3@address.com
4 |Name4|email4@address.com
5 |Name5|email5@address.com
6 |Name6|email6@address.com
```

What I am looking for is some script that will go through a column and add a 2nd emailadd with a "," in the middle so that it'll look like this:

```
ID|Name |email
1 |Name1|email1@address.com,secondemail@address.com
2 |Name2|email2@address.com,secondemail@address.com
3 |Name3|email3@address.com,secondemail@address.com
4 |Name4|email4@address.com,secondemail@address.com
5 |Name5|email5@address.com,secondemail@address.com
6 |Name6|email6@address.com,secondemail@address.com
```

While all of the beginning data remains intact. Please let me know if this is possible. Also the "secondemail@address.com" is just one email address it doesn't change per user. I just need this format for a business reason.

Comment: consider voting up answer if it was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT * REPLACE(email || ',secondemail@address.com' AS email)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question, as in below example

```
#standardSQL 
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Name1' name, 'email1@address.com' email UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Name2', 'email2@address.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Name3', 'email3@address.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Name4', 'email4@address.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Name5', 'email5@address.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Name6', 'email6@address.com' 
)
SELECT * REPLACE(email || ',secondemail@address.com' AS email)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row id  name    email    
1   1   Name1   email1@address.com,secondemail@address.com   
2   2   Name2   email2@address.com,secondemail@address.com   
3   3   Name3   email3@address.com,secondemail@address.com   
4   4   Name4   email4@address.com,secondemail@address.com   
5   5   Name5   email5@address.com,secondemail@address.com   
6   6   Name6   email6@address.com,secondemail@address.com
```

Comment: NULL/missing value in the email is not considered !